# Customize Color Using Lighter in BarChart

Tags: colors, wolfram-mathematica, bar-chart

Please Consider :

```
 dalist = {{901, 503, 522, 1305}, {910, 512, 477, 1260}, 
           {847, 459, 556, 1275}, {799, 517, 527, 1197}}

 cogColors = {RGBColor[0, 0, 1], RGBColor[1, 0, 0], RGBColor[0, 1, 0], RGBColor[1, 1, 0]}

 BarChart[dalist, ChartStyle -> cogColors]
```

[image]

I don`t understand how to assign color to list and to value within the list.

Here my hope is to get each sublist ( first one being : {901, 503, 522, 1305}) assigned one color (Part[[]] of cogColors). Then each bar would be a darker/lighter but similar color. Below is the desired output (ppt) :

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
BarChart[dalist, ChartStyle -> {cogColors, Opacity /@ {0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1}}]
```

[image]

The crux lies in the following sentence in the doc page of ChartStyle:

> With the form ChartStyle->{spec_1, spec_2, ...}, the i, j, ... element in a nested list of
>   datasets has a style given by applying spec_1[[i]], then
>   spec_2[[j]], etc.

This means you have to find directives that have cumulative effects. The combination of Opacity and colors has this. If you combine various colors you end up with the last one.

Comment: @Sjoerd +10 for understanding THAT sentence in the doc page

Comment: @belisarius yeah, cryptic ain't it?

Comment: If you wanted more control over exactly how the colours lighten, and whether they "fade" to white or some other colour, have a look at the `Blend` function http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Blend.html. I'm not near a Mathematica installation right now, so I won't post this as an answer.

Comment: Another thing - `Opacity` doesn't always play nice with EPS graphics, so if you are planning to export these for publication, best to do so as PDF.

Comment: @verbeia I don't think Blend could be made to work as above with ChartStyle. You can use it to make color blends and ranges, but I don't see how you would use it in this multi-dimensional context.

Comment: @Sjoerd, you are right, this won't work with `ChartStyle` - I should have posted the comment under belisarius's answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
BarChart[MapThread[
  Style, {dalist, 
   Transpose@
    Reverse@NestList[Lighter, {Red, Green, Blue, Yellow}, 3]}, 2]]
```

[image]

**Edit by Verbeia**

You can use `Blend` and this approach of `MapThread` and `Style` to get whatever color combinations you want, eg:

```
extColours = 
 Outer[Blend[{#1, GrayLevel[0.1]}, #2] &, cogColors, {0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8}];

BarChart[MapThread[Style, {dalist, extColours}, 2]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You, it seems you both answered within the same minute !

Comment: Correcting my earlier comment, belisarius's answer can work with `Blend` as well. `extColours = 
 Outer[Blend[{#1, GrayLevel[0.1]}, #2] &, 
  cogColors, {0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8}]` and `BarChart[MapThread[Style, {dalist, extColours}, 2]]` - obviously different colours than the other examples. (@belisarius - I'm going to propose this as an edit to your answer. I don't quite have edit privileges yet so rollback if you prefer once it's moderated)

Comment: @Verbeia I approved your edit. Curiously, my opinion is not enough for SO, so other editors must approve before the modification can be sen

Comment: @belisarius are you sure? The two-rep points just came through

Comment: Ah, FAQ on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78799/why-multiple-approvers-for-proposed-edits